# Invalid key hash. Error when i logging in to the game via facebook

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I’ve got error when logging in to the game via Facebook.

Its appeared when I released the game in beta. 
[image]
As far as I understand, that error comes from the fact that one key is used during development, and when releasing its using other key. And because I do not have a release key, as far as I understand.

What have I tried to fix it:

1. I manually rewrote the hash from the error message and placed it into the appropriate field on the devs facebook account.
2. I tried to generate a release hash as it is written in the Facebook documentation. keytool -exportcert -alias YOUR_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS -keystore YOUR_RELEASE_KEY_PATH | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64 .
3. Googled a similar error and tried methods from other forums with similar problem.

Maybe I'm doing something wrong? I have my own .keystore for the game. And yes, all these methods generated keys for me. I have ten of them at this moment. And all of them are now hanging on the devs account.

I have a few questions:

1. Can it be due to the fact that a bunch of keys is hanging on the devs account? There are not only keys for development, but also
   those of my attempts to generate a release key.
2. Do I need to rebuild and re-upload (release) the game after each attempt to get the key?
3. You may ask why I have so many keys. Perhaps this is the problem. Maybe I do not quite understand how to correctly fill
   YOUR_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS and YOUR_RELEASE_KEY_PATH in the code from
   Facebook that I quoted above.  The question itself: Do I fill these
   fields correctly? YOUR_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS Alias from the
   screencapture.YOUR_RELEASE_KEY_PATH is that traced path to the key
   file indicating the key name and extension?

[image]